# No servlet class has been specified for servlet [jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application]

Tags: java

When i try any path I get status 500  No servlet class has been specified for servlet [jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application] the first time and when i do it again it changes to status 404.

My web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

<servlet>

        <!--        each project (in this case the bikeDealer) is bootstrapped with the a servlet-->
        <!--        this is basically the name of the servlet-->
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>

        <!--        firstly there should be servlet-class name to specify which class is being used by the servlet.-->
        <!--        Then there should be init param thingy that should specify which exact package to look for when-->
        <!--        the url has for example "bikes" after the "rest" thingy
                    ** BECAUSE then JERSEY WOULD KNOW WHICH PACKAGE TO LOOK FOR AND
                    THEN he can see which class has the annotation for the path-->

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>

        <!--        any request what is coming on this project (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) is been handled by the this servlet class-->
        <!--        that servlet is basically mapped with the url pattern "rest", so after that "rest" what we put is handled by the
                    "JERSEY" servlet
                    What the JERSEY servlet do is basically it reads the code that we write (which is basically the class that we put after
                    the rest) and processes it. -->

        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>sign-in.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml:
[pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMQ52.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As the exception message (and the comment within the `<servlet>` element tells you: you have no `<servlet-class>` defined within the `<servlet>` element.

Your web.xml needs to at least look like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>

        <!--        each project (in this case the bikeDealer) is bootstrapped with the a servlet-->
        <!--        this is basically the name of the servlet-->
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>

        <!--        firstly there should be servlet-class name to specify which class is being used by the servlet.-->
        <servlet-class>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-class>

        <!--        Then there should be init param thingy that should specify which exact package to look for when-->
        <!--        the url has for example "bikes" after the "rest" thingy
                    ** BECAUSE then JERSEY WOULD KNOW WHICH PACKAGE TO LOOK FOR AND
                    THEN he can see which class has the annotation for the path-->

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>

        <!--        any request what is coming on this project (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) is been handled by the this servlet class-->
        <!--        that servlet is basically mapped with the url pattern "rest", so after that "rest" what we put is handled by the
                    "JERSEY" servlet
                    What the JERSEY servlet do is basically it reads the code that we write (which is basically the class that we put after
                    the rest) and processes it. -->

        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>sign-in.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I guessed the name of the servlet class from the servlet name.